# Static files no Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Opa gente, não estou conseguindo carregar arquivos estáticos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a pasta static está na aplicação core, também testei com ela na raiz do projeto e também não pegou

Fiz um arquivo index de teste:

```
{% load static %}

{% static "assets/css/bootstrap.css"%}

<link href="{% static "assets/css/bootstrap.css"%}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Da o seguinte erro no console do navegador:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/ [HTTP/1.0 200 OK 3 ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/assets/css/bootstrap.css [HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 7 ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/assets/css/bootstrap.css [HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 0 ms]
```

Segui a documentação do django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.11/howto/static-files/ , mas acho que fiz algo de errado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A primeira coisa a se fazer é checar qual o PATH do seus arquivos estáticos, ou seja para onde você esta mandando eles.

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Esse seria um exemplo muito comum em um ambiente de desenvolvimento. Os seus arquivos estatísticos são servidos em uma pasta denominada 'static' na raiz do seu projeto, ou seja: onde o arquivo *manage.py* está.

Em seu caso em particular, nao sei bem ao certo o porque de ter mais uma pasta dentro de 'statics' chamada 'assets'. Talvez vc queira criar uma pasta 'media' **dentro** do static ? Não sei. 
De qualquer forma tente remover a pasta assets e deixar os arquivos estaticos dentro da pasta static somente:

```
-static
----css
----fonts
----img
----js
```

E fazer o carregamento dos arquivos:

```
{% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}"> #exemplo tirado de um projeto pessoal em funcionamento.
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Abraços

Answer (score 1):

O django procura por default (desde que vc tenha o middler django.contrib.staticfiles no seu settings) na pasta static de cada aplicacao e quando vc roda o collectstatic ele copia tudo para a pasta setada na constante STATIC_ROOT.
Uma vez que vc colocou os arquivos staticos em core/static/assets

Tente fazer:

```
<link href="{% static "core/static/assets/css/bootstrap.css"%}" rel="stylesheet">
```